# Why do I need to check both params and request.headers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an api method in a Rails controller like the following:

```
 def login
    if !request || !request.headers
      render :json => {:error => I18n.t('error_must_provide_api_key_or_token')}, :status => :unauthorized and return
    end

    api_key = params['X-Api-Key']

    if api_key.nil?
      api_key = request.headers['X-Api-Key']
    end

    ... rest of method ...
```

The method first checks to see if we have a request, and whether that request has headers. Then, what I *want* to do is check for a header variable called `X-Api-Key`. I first check the `params` hash, and, if there isn't one found there, I then check the `request.headers` hash.

What I don't understand is why I have to check *both* of these. Previously, I had:

```
api_key = request.headers['X-Api-Key']
```

This works when I'm debugging on my local machine, but it doesn't work once I push to my production server and run in production mode. Conversely, the following:

```
api_key = params['X-Api-Key']
```

Works when I push to the production server, but doesn't work when running locally.

My local machine is running MacOS, and rbenv 1.1.0 with ruby 2.4.0p0 and rails 5.1.1.

My server is Ubuntu 16.04 and running ruby 2.1.4p265 with rails 4.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

- Request headers are coming from the http headers.
- While params are from the body of the HTTP (if its not GET method), or from the encoded url (e.g: something like http://localhost:3000/cars?a=b, then params[:a] would give 'b').

---

e.g (using curl, -H stands for header)

using url encoded for the params,

`curl -H 'X-Api-Key: 1234' http://localhost:3000/cars?X-Api-Key=abc`

or using http request body, with  `application/json` as content-type.

`curl -X GET -H 'X-Api-Key: 1234' -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{"X-Api-Key": "abc" }' http://localhost:3000/cars`

- Then, `request.headers['X-Api-Key]` would returns `1234`
- while `params['X-Api-Key']` would returns `abc`.

---

So what happened here is likely, in local you are sending the `X-Api-Key`, through http header, while in production you are sending it through url encoded or http request body as content-type as json.

To solve this,

- if you want to support both ways, to feed X-Api-Key

  - through http header
  - http encoded params or json params in the http body

  Then what you wrote above make sense.
- if you want to only support http header, then change your production client code, to send X-Api-Key through http request header.
- if you want to only support params, then change your local code, to send X-Api-Key, through http request body or encoded url.

Comment: No, this actually isn't correct. I'm sending them both the same way, as I'm sending both requests through postman to test them. The only difference is that I change the environment in which postman operates (i.e. the host, port, and protocol type)

Comment: Do you use reverse proxy ? If yes do you modify the the url to pass request header of X-Api-Key to the encoded url ?

Comment: I'm actually not sure. I have it set up using Apache with Phusion Passenger to serve rails... so maybe? How would I go about making sure the headers are sent?